# How can I run the Trickle bandwidth throttler as daemon (trickled) on start-up?

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, daemon, throttling

I want to run the bandwidth throttler `trickled` automatically on boot up. (Raspbian OS on the Raspberry Pi). What methods are there, and which one(s) are standard practice? The options I've found are summarised [here](http://raspberrywebserver.com/serveradmin/run-a-script-on-start-up.html), perhaps there are other ways too.

I will want to set up a config file for `trickled` which will throttle different programs with different priorities, as per the example [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/control-your-bandwidth-trickle).

I presume that with the above example, `trickle(d)` needs to be run with the config file before the programs it applies to are run? (e.g. vncserver, ssh server, samba, etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the info in the link you posted, you should be able to use the [init-script I've written](https://github.com/default50/scriptery/blob/master/init-scripts/trickled), along with the [config file](https://github.com/default50/scriptery/blob/master/init-scripts/default-trickled) for it. Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Raspbian.

You should copy the init-script into `/etc/init.d` and the config file should be renamed and placed in `/etc/default/trickled`. Make sure the init-script is executable with:

```
sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/trickled
```

And after that enable the service to be run at boot with:

```
sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/trickled defaults
```

The configuration file for the daemon isn't strictly necessary in my experience, unless you need to set per-application priority or define time and/or length-soothing parameters.

Just make sure you run your processes with `trickle -n <my_socket_path> my_process` in case you change the default socket path.